# Surf and Mesh stopped working in Matlab

Tags: matlab, runtime-error

My surf and mesh functions have stopped working properly in Matlab r2014b. Calling them with the following example taken from the official documentation:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:0.5:10,1:20);
Z = sin(X) + cos(Y);
surf(X,Y,Z);
```

throws the following error:

```
Error using surf (line 57)
Not enough input arguments.
```

Both functions used to work a few days ago. Every other plotting function (e.g. plot3) I've tried still works.

Please help me!

Comment: Did you create a file called `surf.m`? Type `which surf` to see what MATLAB thinks the `surf` function is. If it doesn't point into the MATLAB toolbox directory, you done screw up! :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo I typed `which surf` and got: `/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/toolbox/matlab/graph3d/surf.m`.

Comment: Are you sure it’s the code you show here that throws the error? Does this persist after restarting MATLAB? Are you defining a variable named surf? If you do `clear surf` just above this bit of code, do you still get the error? — Lots of questions, but this is odd behavior...

Comment: I realized the problem was that I had a function named `error.m`. After renaming the function things got to work again. Thanks for your help! @CrisLuengo